# Tkinter file directory to save output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I have these functions that prompt user to load csv file via a GUI (Tkinter) to perform basic statistics and correlation matrix. The out is saved on a working directory.
I dont want to specify the directory in the code but that the user will be able to choose a directory if choice. I want to modify this code to change the static directory and give some flexibility for the user to select where to save it. Please help. New to python

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import statsmodels.api as sm
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root= tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 500,  relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='EDA')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Number of Clusters:')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 8))
canvas1.create_window(200, 120, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)
```

def getExcel ():

```
global df
import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
df = pd.read_csv (import_file_path, parse_dates = date_cols, index_col = 'TimeStamp') 
   


browseButtonExcel = tk.Button(text=" Import Excel File (CSV) ", command=getExcel, bg='green',  fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 70, window=browseButtonExcel)

def descriptiv(): #def descriptiv(self, df, path, filename):
    stats = df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
    stats['variance'] = df.var()
    stats['pct missing'] = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100 
    #folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory() # I want to be able to use this to prompt the user to select a directory to save the file
    return stats.to_csv('C:/Users/chall/Desktop/work/descriptive.csv') # I want to change this so user can decide where to save the output

def correl():
    matri = df.corr(method = 'pearson').to_csv('C:/Users/chall/Desktop/work/correlation.csv') #same problem here.
    return matri

processButton2 = tk.Button(text=' Descriptive Statistics',  command= descriptiv, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=processButton2)  

processButton3 = tk.Button(text=' Correlation Matrix',  command= correl, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=processButton3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As to open a file you used file dialog's filedialog.askopenfilename(), similarly Tkinter file dialogue also provides you an option filedialog.asksaveasfilename(). Try this it will allow  the user to select the output path without displaying the path in your code.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I am pretty new to python so I am having a hard time to pass the out put into calling the tkinter's filedialog.savesfilename(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: stats.to_csv('C:/Users/chall/Desktop/work/descriptive.csv') replace this with stats.askopenfilename()

Comment: Also, make sure you import it from file dialog